# Regular expression to get base url

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc-2

I got a very long string that cointains querystrings and and some regular site urls in it. it looks something like

```
http://www.mysite.com/site/site?pageId=1234&otherId=4321
```

I would like to get just the `http://www.mysite.com` from this string. Im thinking maybe a regular expression could do the trick, but Im def not quilfied to write any of that :) so could i get some help?

**EDIT**
i need a solution so i can pass url string and get the base url from that. Not my current Url

thanks guys, appreciate it as always.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this:

```
string uri = Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority);
```

You can check with this also:

```
var url = new Uri("http://www.mysite.com/site/site?pageId=1234&otherId=4321");
string uri = url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority);
```

Comment: I cant use that. its a string that generate urls like .se, .co.uk ect with that full url. So im not getting the current url

Comment: Means..? I am not getting what you say..@Dejan.S

Comment: Have tried with this because this is the working solution..I have updated my answer for your clarification @Dejan.S

Comment: no its not for my situation, Im sorry it was a bit unclear. I got generated strings in a string array thats passed to my method, so its not about requesting my current url, i have to process a array of urls (hope this make sense), but anyway i found out how to do it. i posted the answer above.

Answer (score 0):

Solution

```
var url = new Uri("http://www.mydomain.com/Site/Subsite?page=site");
var baseUrl = url.Host;
```

Comment: Then you have to update your question because you are expecting something else with the question you have posted..

Comment: i edited my question, but it say string multiple times wich indicates i got a string not my current url. but my bad its a bit unclear

Answer (score 0):

As the author asked for a regular expression, that's it:

```
 static string ExtractBaseUrl(string url)
        {
            Regex regex = new Regex(@"^https?:\/\/[^\/]+");
            Match resultm = regex.Match(url);
            if (resultm.Success)
            return resultm.Groups[0].Value;
            else return null;
        }
```

Comment: Try to add some explanation to your answer, so it does not appear on the low quality posts queue.